# Automorphism group of vector space

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

I was trying to understand definition of representation and trivial representation thus came across the case where $ V= K $ here $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$ 
and thus $Aut_K (V) \cong K^{*}$ but I am not quite clear about this automorphism groups. 
I understand that we need invertible etc. but can someone explain this group ? 
the elements of this group.

EDIT ( another Q) :

and also if we have dim$(V)$ = $n$ then we can say $Aut_K (V) \cong GL_{n} (K) $ is it just because every map $f \in Aut_K (V) $ can be expressed as $ [f]_{\beta}$ for some $\beta \in K$ to give $[f]_{\beta} \in GL_{n} (K) $ is this true ?

Answer (score 4):

$K^*$ is the group of all non zero elements of the field $K$ under multiplication. Basically, all this is saying is that all automorphisms from a field to itself is given by multiplication by a non zero element of the field. To see why this is true, show that any such automorphism is determined by the image of a certain special element.

Comment: thanks. 
Could you help me with the edited part in Q too ?

Comment: @sammath: Usually the community norm is to not edit the question, but to post it as a separate question. I would request you to post this as a separate question. You can link the new question to this one, saying that you wanted to ask a follow up question.

Comment: @sammath: Though your proof for the edited question is correct :).

Comment: Thanks. Will remember and do it the next time !

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* First note that any non-zero element of $K$ can be taken as a basis of the vector space. Now you can send $1$ to any of these non-zero elements and that will give you an automorphism.